# Python generate custom combinations of sub lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm generating a custom combination of sub lists without using `itertools`.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
input =  [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 3]]
output = [[1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4, 3]]

def getList():
    a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 3]]
    return(a)

c=[]                        # output list
l = len(getList())
for i in range(l):
    for j in range(i+1,l):
        a=getList()
        a[i].extend(a[j])
        c.append(a[i])
```

As the `extend()` updates the input list, I defined a function to redefine the input. Is it a recommended practice? What could be improved here?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `itertools`? Because using `itertools` is recommended practice...

Comment: @Peilonrayz no reason as such, was just trying how to achieve without it.

Comment: @VanPeer You have a hardcoded `input()` in `get_List()`, what would happen if the input changes?

Comment: These are not all combinations of a list

Comment: @Ludisposed thanks! assuming input doesn't change. i needed only the combinations specified in the `output`. i didn't mention all combinations, did i? anyways, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a function.
2. Don't mutate data you don't want to be mutated.

   Rather than using `list.extend`, use `list.__add__`. However don't use `list.__iadd__`, as that has the same problem as `list.extend`.
3. Learn how to copy Python objects. You can use `list([1, 2, 3])` to make a copy of the list. You can also use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) library too.
4. Don't waste memory, just `yield`. If you need a list use `list(product(...))`

```
def product(input):
    for i in range(len(input)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(input)):
            yield input[i] + input[j]
```

Comment: Yield is better then mine, memorywise, but don't use `input` as a variable name. :)

Comment: @Ludisposed You could always use a generator, rather than list, comprehension. And shadowing built-ins is fine IMO. It's not like the OP's going to use the original `input` in the function.

Comment: I just try to avoid shadowing built ins, at all costs! Maybe just a bit paranoid :$

Comment: @Ludisposed There are good arguments for and good against. I don't think you'll confuse `input` as `builtins.input` in a small 4 lines of code function. If however it were a 200 line function I'd whole heartedly agree. I do admit it's not that great a variable name, but we don't have context to improve on that.

Comment: @Peilonrayz thanks for this, seems really simple!

Answer (score 4):

> What could be improved here?

*@thnx Peilonrayz, a generator expression will work better on large inputs*

1. Use a nested generator expression.
2. DON'T hardcode variables, this will make your code very static.
3. Make a function, to accept different variables.

---

```
def custom_combo(L):
    return (L[i] + L[j] for i in range(len(L)) for j in range(i+1, len(L)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 3]]
    print(list(custom_combo(a)))
```